# How to set partition size for date field in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, partitioning, delta-lake

I have timestamp field `source_timestamp` which is used a lot in the queries to the delta table.
I would like to partition by this column with size of the partition = 1 month.
How to achieve that?

If I create field `source_timestamp_month` and partition by it - will this partition be used if users still will mostly run queries using `source_timestamp` column in where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning the table by the new `source_timestamp_month` will not help if users are running queries using `source_timestamp`.

What you really need is partitioning by expression - which is not supported by Delta. However, you can try using [generated columns](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/generated-columns.html). Partition filters can be derived on generated columns, however there are limitations. The documentation explains the limitations in detail.

```
CREATE TABLE log(
  log_timestamp timestamp,
  id INT,
  event STRING,
  generated_year INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(log_timestamp)),
  generated_month INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MONTH(log_timestamp))
)
PARTITIONED BY (generated_year, generated_month);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your table already exists ,

```
ALTER TABLE your_database.your_table
ADD COLUMN source_timestamp_month STRING;
```

-- Update the new column with the month portion

```
   UPDATE your_database.your_table
   SET source_timestamp_month = date_format(source_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM');
```

So that you can easily filter the data based on the partitioned columns

```
SELECT *
FROM your_database.your_table
WHERE source_timestamp_month = '2023-09';
```